# Wikidata SPARQL interface: order by random

Tags: random, sparql, wikidata

I've been playing a little bit with the Wikidata SPARQL page ([here](http://query.wikidata.org)), and I was wondering if we can shuffle the order of the results set randomly.

I tried the following example, and I left the random part as a comment cause I couldn't find the correct syntax for it:

```
SELECT ?partyLabel ?countryLabel ?count
WHERE{
?party wdt:P31 wd:Q7278.
  ?party wdt:P17 ?country.
  ?party wdt:P2124 ?count
SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en".}
}
order by #random
limit 15
```

Did anyone try the random ordering option? and does it exist?

Comment: Try `ORDER BY uuid()`. Neither `ORDER BY rand()` nor `BIND(rand() AS ?rand) } ORDER BY ?rand` shouldn't work on Wikidata even with `hint:Query hint:optimizer "None" .` Please note that both browser and server cache results. Add a few spaces every time :).

Comment: @StanislavKralin thanks ! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possible candidates are:

- [`RAND()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#idp2130040)
- [`BNODE()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-bnode)
- [`UUID()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-uuid)
- [`STRUUID()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-struuid)

However, neither `ORDER BY RAND()` nor `ORDER BY BNODE()` works on Wikidata even with `hint:Query hint:optimizer "None"` ([that's why](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3FpartyLabel%20%3FcountryLabel%20%3Fcount%20%3Frand%0AWHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%3Fparty%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ7278.%0A%20%20%3Fparty%20wdt%3AP17%20%3Fcountry.%0A%20%20%3Fparty%20wdt%3AP2124%20%3Fcount%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22%5BAUTO_LANGUAGE%5D%2Cen%22%20%7D%0A%20%20BIND%20%28RAND%28%29%20AS%20%3Frand%29%0A%7D%20ORDER%20BY%20%3Frand%20LIMIT%2015%0A)).

As for `UUID()` and `STRUUID()`, it seems that there is no significant performance difference, so you can use any of them.

Please note that both browser and server [cache](https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T126730) results, hence, add a few spaces or commented current time to every query.

**Update**

With a single triple pattern, one can use [the sample service](https://github.com/blazegraph/database/blob/master/bigdata-core/bigdata-rdf/src/java/com/bigdata/rdf/sparql/ast/eval/SampleServiceFactory.java#L74).